# c, Import text file with different lines and handle the lines

Tags: c, text-files, scanf

im trying to make a little program that reads a chat log and calculates some numbers.
Thing is im not sure what command to use since the lines arent identical.
Heres a few lines from the log

[22:56:37] Your strike was absorbed by a magical barrier!

[22:56:37] You miss!

[22:56:37] You attack Tylaia with your bright arcanium weighted bearded axe and hit for 70 (-41) damage!

[22:56:37] You critical hit Tylaia for an additional 19 damage!

[22:56:37] You hit Tylaia for 66 (-21) damage!

[22:56:37] You hit Tylaia for 17 extra damage!

[22:56:37] Tniatha hits your hand with her bright duskwood exceptional buckler for 72 damage!

[22:56:37] Tniatha critical hits you for an additionnal 32 damage!

[22:56:37] Tniatha does 8 extra damage to you!

[22:56:37] Tniatha hits you for 8 damage !

[22:56:37] You are enveloped in a cloud of dirt!

How can I import only the lines where the "damage" is done?

This is what i have so far;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    char your_self[15], char who_ever_else[15];
    int damage_done, damage_taken, healing_done, healing_taken;
} input;


int main(void){
    input *inputArray = malloc(1);
    read_log_file(&inputArray);
    return 0;
}

void read_log_file(input **inputArray, int *lineCount){
    char your_self[15], char who_ever_else[15];
    int damage_done, damage_taken, healing_done, healing_taken;

    FILE *inputFile;
    inputFile=fopen("chat.log", "r");
    if(inputFile = NULL){
        printf("File cant open");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Was thinking to do something like this;p

```
  (fscanf(inputFile, ".............."...
```

But then since every line is not identical ill get the wrong values into my variables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find if the word "damage" is contained within a line:

```
if (strstr(line, "damage") != NULL) {
    /* "damage" found */
}
```

Comment: I actually knew that one haha :D im still not awake i guess, thank you :)

Comment: But hmm I'll still get some different lines with that, so how can i use fscanf to find the numbers i want to?

Comment: @Winkz You better not use `scanf()`. Use `fgets()` instead, and perhaps look for the first number after the word `"damage"` or whatever.

Comment: Okay thank you :) gonna look up getline, havent used it before

Comment: @Winkz Damn, sorry, I meant `fgets()`.

Comment: Done sorry, totally forgot about it :D

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a similar code. Guess this will help

```
char *match;

/* Read line by line - fgets reads only till a newline/ EOF - u can refer help*/
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
{
    /* Search for pattern */
    match = strstr(buffer,"damage");

    if (match != NULL)
    {
                  //Do ur stuff
                 }
     }
```

Comment: Would you know how i can read a number right infront of a word?

Comment: @Winkz I had in my program, that at end of the pattern there will be version of the program. I used as int HexFileVersion; char MajorVer[2];  MajorVer[0] = Version[strlen(pattern)];
          MajorVer[1] = Version[strlen(pattern)+1];                 HexFileVersion  = (int) strtol(MajorVer, NULL, 16);

Comment: I used 16 in strtol cos it is a hexadecimal number and the base is 16