# Looping over an input line and calling a function in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

I wrote a small rgrep function and I'll have another text file with words that I am checking a pattern against.
My text file will be in the following format.

```
a
because 
cat 
7.*
```

How do i write a loop that will call a function for each of those words in the file? Thanks!

Comment: What specifically can't you manage with that? Looks like any ordinary looping construct could be used. Could you show what you've tried so far please?

Comment: Try searching fopen, fread, fclose, fgets, strchr functions and read about them. You will soon figure out the whole code to do what you have asked for. :-D

Comment: `int rgrep_matches(char *line, char *pattern)` is my rgrep function and I guess my input line might be something like this:                  'm', 'y', 'I', 'n', 'p', 'u', 't', '\n', '\0'. I guess I was confused because I can run it as `$./rgrep '\.hi' < input.txt` in Terminal. So would it be valid to write a for-loop under rgrep_matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a state machine for that pattern first, then every char drives that state machine to next state. Check state to check pattern match.

Answer (score 1):

Try using fopen to open file and read line by line using fgets

Check this post too
[c, Import text file with different lines and handle the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246437/c-import-text-file-with-different-lines-and-handle-the-lines/15247015#15247015)